# SP2010 JSOM: when creating field using JavaScript, how to define date only instead of date & time

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, client-object-model

I create a list using:

```
function createProjectList() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title('Projects');
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(100);
    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
    clientContext.load(oList);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCreatedProjectList), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

and then I use this to define the list

```
function onCreatedProjectList() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Project');

    //what is the setter/property for define the following field as date only instead of date and time. DateTime is just the internal type, so ?
    this.fieldValue = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'ProjectDueDate\' Type=\DateTime\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
    var fieldVal = clientContext.castTo(fieldValue ,SP.FieldNumber);
    fieldVal.update();
    clientContext.load(fieldValue );

    fieldCollection = oList.get_fields();
    this.oneField = fieldCollection.getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");
    this.oneField.set_hidden(true);
    this.oneField.set_defaultValue('...');
    this.oneField.set_required(false);
    this.oneField.update();
    clientContext.load(this.fieldCollection);
    clientContext.load(this.oneField);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCompletedProjectList), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
Format=\'DateOnly\'
```

to xml field definition.

So, that line in your code would be:

```
this.fieldValue = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'ProjectDueDate\' Type=\DateTime\' Format=\'DateOnly\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
```